# Is Azure SDK for ruby going to have support for Azure IOT hub/Event hub?

Tags: azure, logstash

I wish to write a custom plugin for logstash which allows me to pull data form Azure IOT Hub/Event hub by leveraging Azure SDK for ruby. The SDK currently does not support that. Any one knows if it is in the Roadmap ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a product roadmap question. There's no way to have this answered here.

Comment: Azure SDK for ruby is a git hub project. I will reach out to the project team thankls

Comment: I'm well aware it's a github project. But the engineering team cannot comment on unannounced features / plans.

Comment: @David Makogon got you

Comment: @DavidMakogon perhaps they should. The ASP.NET team even holds public standup meetings after all and the Azure SDK is a convenience wrapper over the REST APIs. At the very least this would help others decide whether to implement their own libraries (perhaps even make a PR of them) or wait for MS.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - perhaps, indeed. But that's not my call. :)  In any case, StackOverflow isn't the place to ask roadmap questions.

Comment: @DavidMakogon that's debatable - when an OSS project isn't open enough, where do you ask? There are a lot of similar questions in SO. Given the upcoming IoT battle between AWS and Azure, I strongly think a clear roadmap is necessary.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Feel free to create a chat to discuss this with others, or post on a discussion forum, tweet about it, etc.. Regardless how you feel about this, it's not a programming question and is off-topic for StackOverflow. And your opinion of needing a clear roadmap is... an opinion (as is your perspective on an IoT battle, which has nothing to do with programming q&a). This isn't the place for debating the merits of publishing roadmaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby client support beyond what's in the current SDK (the Queue client should quite well be able to send to EH) isn't very high up on our demand-driven list of priorities for Event Hubs. Java, Node, Python, and C/C++ simply rank higher. That doesn't mean that we're not going to make that better, it's just not the first thing on the backlog.

That said, the [Apache Qpid Proton AMQP 1.0 stack has a binding for Ruby](https://github.com/apache/qpid-proton/tree/master/proton-c/bindings/ruby) and that should work against Event Hubs. AMQP is required to pull data out, send can be done via HTTPS and AMQP.

[Michael Lanzetta has a summary of what is required](http://www.mikelanzetta.com/2014/11/talking-to-eventhub-with-amqp-1-0/) for a bare implementation of an AMQP 1.0 consumer for EH and we're going to improve the docs for direct AMQP access shortly.

Comment: Thanks for sharing usefull info, will give it a shot !

Comment: if you are running using jRuby and can't use the c-bindings you can use http://qpid.apache.org/components/jms/ or do something similar to what is described here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-java-how-to-use-amqp/